# sql of INSERT INTO to branch to two tables on a condition?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named tbl_A and tbl_B respectively. I'd like to insert a record into tbl_B on existance of the record in tbl_A. Is there single sql statement for that? I think INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not the one I want.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  We can't answer it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that with WHERE EXISTS. Here is an example but what you want may be a little more involving but yes you can do that.

```
INSERT INTO contacts
(id, name)
SELECT supp_id, supp_name
FROM suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM orders
              WHERE suppliers.supp_id = orders.supp_id);
```

Comment: I understood the code you said and works well in my program. Thanks